# Convert Image type to Nvarchar in DataBase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I created a database in SQL Server 2014.

Type my record is `image`. Now I decided to change the type to `Nvarchar(255)` but I get this error

[image: Error]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You should be converting it to `varbinary`, not `varchar`.

Comment: You can't do this. An image is NOT the same thing as nvarchar(255).

Comment: I Need Use Name of Image

Comment: Does this table have any data in it yet? Are you just fixing a design time mistake or is there existing data in that column? If so what is that like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate your table, the easiest way for me is doing the following in Management studio.

1.- Select you existing table, right click, 
2.-  Select "Script table as"
3.-  Select "Drop and Create To"
4.- Select "new query windows"

One new query windows will be shown and you can change your data type and run the script, this will drop your existing table and create the new one with the new data type (all your existing data will be deleted"

Comment: i Need Name of Image

Comment: Means instead of image you want to store only the name of the image?